# Is p:media incompatible with view scope?

Tags: jsf, glassfish

I am using jsf 2.1 in a web project with primefaces 3.5 and glassfish 3.2.

When I use p:media tag along with a view scoped managed bean, an error occurs indicating an xml parsing error.

Comment: Can you post the exact error? Maybe also add some code.

Comment: Errors represent the whole answer. Being unable to interpret it doesn't mean that you should hide it from others being able to interpret it and translate it for you in layman's terms. In other words, copypaste the whole error unmodified in your question, along with an SSCCE reproducing it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty shure if this leadds to the same problem like with using `Richfaces` and its `a4j:mediaOutput`. There you cannot use it in ViewScope but here is a [link](https://community.jboss.org/thread/168523) to a workaround. I hope it fits to your problem.